# ipython %timeit "local variable 'a' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, ipython, timeit

I am trying to the run the following code but I get a `local variable 'a' referenced before assignment.`

```
a = [x for x in range(10)]
b = [x for x in range(10)]
%timeit a+=b
```

The statement works without the `%timeit` magic.

Is there something I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried `%timeit $a+=$b`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer but that does not work. Neither surrounding the expression with braces. I thought the "$" and {braces} are only used when making system calls!

Comment: yeah, sorry, too quick. Reopening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you expect it to do?

Outside of the timeit it does:

```
In [188]: a += b
In [189]: a
Out[189]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I tried initializing `x`, and got a near infinite loop, eventually ending with a memory error

```
In [192]: %%timeit x=a
     ...: x += b

In [194]: len(a)
Out[194]: 529076630
```

In other words each timeit loop concatenated another list of `b` values to `x` (and by extension `a`), resulting are very long loop.  I suspect an individual `x+=b` was fast, resulting in `timeit` choosing to loop many times.

Lets create an `a` fresh each loop:

```
In [196]: %%timeit
     ...: a = [x for x in range(10)]
     ...: a += b
     ...: 
1.91 µs ± 4.82 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

This produces the memory error as well:

```
In [197]: %%timeit a = [x for x in range(10)]
     ...: a += b
```

If I control the number of loops:

```
In [202]: %%timeit -n 100 a = [x for x in range(10)]
     ...: a += b
     ...: 
     ...: 
208 ns ± 11 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

With `ns` times I can see why the default loops is so large.

I haven't tried timing a plain `a+=...` before (not even with numpy arrays), but evidently it expects some sort of local initialization for that `a`, either within the loop or in the initialization block.  But it is important to keep in mind that the timed actions may be performed many times (the -r and -n parameters or the default values).  So any in-place action might result bit changes to the global values.  In this case `timeit` might be trying to protect us from that kind of unexpected growth, by expecting some sort of 'local' variable.

---

Lets try the `a+b`, but with an assignment:

```
In [215]: c=np.zeros(10)
In [216]: a
Out[216]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
In [217]: b
Out[217]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
In [218]: %timeit c = a+b
5.33 µs ± 105 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [219]: c
Out[219]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Notice that the global `c` has not changed.  The assignment is to a temporary local `c` - even though a global of the same name is available.

As a general rule, calculations performed inside the timing loop should not leak outside the loop.  You have to something explicit as I did in the memory error loop, or here

```
In [222]: %%timeit x = c
     ...: x += b
     ...: 
9.04 µs ± 238 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [223]: c
Out[223]: 
array([       0.,   811111.,  1622222.,  2433333.,  3244444.,  4055555.,
        4866666.,  5677777.,  6488888.,  7299999.])
```

or here:

```
In [224]: c=np.zeros(10)
In [225]: %%timeit x = c
     ...: x[:] = a+b

7.84 µs ± 199 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [226]: c
Out[226]: array([  1.,   3.,   5.,   7.,   9.,  11.,  13.,  15.,  17.,  19.])
```

Both use an in-place assignment to a local variable which has been linked to a mutable global.

Comment: I just expect it to time `a+=b`.
The following commands work:

    %timeit a+b 
    %timeit a.extend(b)
but:
    %timeit a+=b 
returns the error message that `local variable 'a' referenced before assignment.` I just want to understand why `a` is not known in the latter but works with the former.

Comment: Which `a` is it supposed to use during each loop?  The original 10 element list?  Or the `a` produced by the last iteration (which keeps growing)? Or a new empty list?  Do you understand why I got a memory error?

Comment: Details of how the expression is compiled, and how the `user namespace` is passed to it (along with a local namespace) are buried in `timeit` code (not just the magic, but also the underlying `timeit` module.  https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html